# How to store and customize jupyter notebook slide show

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, powerpoint

[image]

I have converted my Jupyter notebook into a slide show. The image is the screenshot of one of my slide shows. Is there any way to only show the plot/output (not the code) of the slide? Also, can we store/save those slides as PowerPoint? This is my first time using jupyter notebook to do the presentation, I googled but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Can you share the code you used to create your slide show? What does the output of the code look like?

Comment: This is just one example, I have attached the screenshot of the slide show. First I would not like to show my slide for full screen(but didn't find the option to make it smaller). Secondly, if I want to show only the plot(or any output) not the code, how to do that?

Comment: You can add some html and css code to get nice jupiter titles and use it during your presentations without converting to ppt or pdf.

Comment: @AEH can you give an example or link which tells detail about it. Never use Html and css code before. I can use the markdown to create a better pdf but never done anything for the presentation slide from jupyter.

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress showing code by passing `--no-input` to `nbconvert`:

```
jupyter nbconvert presentation.ipynb --to slides --no-input --post serve
```

will serve it without the code. I don't know how to make a ppt, I think the best you can do is a pdf slideshow. First save to html (just leave off `--post serve`) and then use [decktape](https://github.com/astefanutti/decktape) to convert the html to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML and CSS to get clean jupyter and save it as pdf or present it directly.

This is some examples:

```
# header
<div style="display: flex; text-align:center; background-color: RGB(  255, 87, 34  );" >
<h1 style="margin: auto; padding: 30px; ">PROJECT 1 - Data Analysis - Python<br>
    Custom HTML, CSS in jupyter Notebook
</h1>
</div>


# outline
<div style="border-style: double;border-width: 5px;border-color: RGB(51,165,182);" >
<h3 style="margin: auto; padding: 10px; color: RGB(51,165,182); ">Parts of the presentation :</h3>
    <div style="margin: auto;padding-left: 40px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <lu>
            <li>Part 1 : Import libraries</li>
            <li>Part 2 : Import and cleaning data</li>
            <li>Part 3 : Analyse data</li>
            <li>Part 4 : Save results </li>
        </lu>
    </div>
</div>



# header H2
<div style="background-color: RGB(51,165,182);" >
<h2 style="margin: auto; padding: 20px; color:#fff; ">Part 1 - Libraries and functions</h2>
</div>



# Header H3
<div style="border: 1px solid RGB(51,165,182);" >
<h3 style="margin: auto; padding: 10px; color: RGB(51,165,182); ">1.1 - Import libraries</h3>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]